# (Docker) Prestashop 8.1 FPM with Nginx - 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: docker, symfony, nginx, prestashop, fpm

I am trying to get Prestashop 8.1 running on Docker as my dev environment, but I can't succeed. First I tried the prestashop:latest image with Apache web server and used Nginx as a SSL Proxy to run it over HTTPS. Everything worked fine **until the Theme Installation step in the installer**; I was getting 504 Gateway Time-out error. Running it just on Apache without Nginx proxy didn't helped. Tried setting the proxy timeout limits to a higher value, still no luck.

I've decided to use FPM image instead. I can access the Prestashop installer correctly, but the original issue with the 504 Gateway Time-out that I had running the Apache image, occurs with the FPM setup too.

**Console log**

```
shopdev      | 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2023:19:34:22 +0000] "GET /install/index.php?installTheme=true&_=1691695967736 HTTP/2.0" 504 569 "https://localhost/install/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
prestashop   | NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/var/cache/pro_/ContainerHOomYsF/getConsole_CommandLoaderService.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/var/cache/pro_/ContainerHOomYsF/appAppKernelProdContainer.php on line 2254
prestashop   | NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/var/cache/pro_/ContainerHOomYsF/getConsole_CommandLoaderService.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/var/cache/pro_/ContainerHOomYsF/appAppKernelProdContainer.php:2254
prestashop   | Stack trace:
prestashop   | #0 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(255): ContainerHOomYsF\appAppKernelProdContainer->load('getConsole_Comm...')
prestashop   | #1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(231): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->make('console.command...', 1)
prestashop   | #2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(184): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('console.command...')
prestashop   | #3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(75): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
prestashop   | #4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput))
prestashop   | #5 /var/www/html/src/Adapter/Cache/Clearer/SymfonyCacheClearer.php(79): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput))
prestashop   | #6 [internal function]: PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\SymfonyCacheClearer->PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\{closure}()
prestashop   | #7 {main}
prestashop   | thrown in /var/www/html/var/cache/pro_/ContainerHOomYsF/appAppKernelProdContainer.php on line 2254
```

*Weird enough the log path says "pro_", but when looking in the directory, I can see "prod".*

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  nginx:  # Nginx web server
    image: nginx:latest  # Latest Nginx Server Image
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - prestashop
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - prestashop_network
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html  # Mount the local src directory to the container
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  # Mount the Nginx config
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl  # Mount the SSL folder to provide certs

  mysql:  # MySQL DB
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest  # Latest MySQL Server Image
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWD}  # MySQL Root Password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}  # Project's database
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}  # Project's database user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_USER_PASSWD}  # Project's database password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - prestashop_network
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql  # Mount the MySQL data volume

  prestashop:  # Prestashop Shop CMS
    container_name: prestashop
    # image: prestashop/prestashop:latest  # Latest Prestashop Apache Image
    image: prestashop/prestashop:8.1.1-8.1-fpm  # FPM Nginx Prestashop Image
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PS_DEV_MODE: ${PS_DEV_MODE} # Development mode
      PS_INSTALL_AUTO: ${PS_INSTALL_AUTO}  # Install Prestashop automatically
      PS_INSTALL_DB: ${PS_INSTALL_DB}  # Create DB on install
      PS_ERASE_DB: ${PS_ERASE_DB}  # Erase DB on install
      PS_ENABLE_SSL: ${PS_ENABLE_SSL}  # Enable SSL on install
      PS_DOMAIN: ${PS_DOMAIN}  # Domain for Prestashop installation
      DB_SERVER: ${PS_DATABASE_SERVER}  # Project's database server
      DB_NAME: ${PS_DATABASE}  # Project's database
      DB_USER: ${PS_DATABASE_USER}  # Project's database user
      DB_PASSWD: ${PS_DATABASE_PASSWD}  # Project's database password
      ADMIN_MAIL: ${PS_ADMIN_MAIL}  # Prestashop admin email
      ADMIN_PASSWD: ${PS_ADMIN_PASSWD}  # Prestashop admin password
      PS_FOLDER_ADMIN: ${PS_FOLDER_ADMIN}  # Prestashop admin folder/url
    networks:
      - prestashop_network
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html  # Mount the local src directory to the container

networks:
  prestashop_network:  # Define a shared network for this setup

volumes:
  mysql-data:  # Define the MySQL data volume
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
   server_name localhost;

   location / {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   http2 on;
   server_name localhost;

   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
   ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
   ssl_session_tickets off;

   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

   index index.php index.html;
   root /var/www/html;
   location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass prestashop:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   }
}
```

Tried running Apache image without Nginx proxy, tried FPM image, changing proxy limits, removing cache manually.

Comment: I was running into the same issue behind nginx proxy manager. Changing the timeout value on the Proxy Host solved the 504 Gateway issue.

Example:
https://github.com/NginxProxyManager/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/257
`proxy_read_timeout 600;`

Comment: After changing the proxy limits this way in my nginx.conf, I solved the error 504. I get the 1: HTTP 500 - error - {"success":true,"message":""} now, and the same PHP errors in the logs as in my original post @UP (appAppKernelProdContainer.php:2254).

```fastcgi_read_timeout 600; proxy_connect_timeout 600; proxy_send_timeout 600; proxy_read_timeout 600; send_timeout 600;
```

Comment: Installing via CGI worked.